# Ratio of two exponential series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I have the following function that I would like to simplify or find a good  bounds on
\begin{align*}
f(x)=\frac{\left(  \sum_{ k=1... N} ke^{-\frac{\left(x- c k \right)^2}{2}} \right)^2}{  \sum_{ k=1... N}  e^{-\frac{\left(x- c k \right)^2}{2}}}
\end{align*}
where $c$ is some positive constant and $N$ is some integer.

A simple bound that I was able to come up is  using  $Ne^{-\frac{\left(x- c k \right)^2}{2}} \ge ke^{-\frac{\left(x- c k \right)^2}{2}} \ge 1 \cdot e^{-\frac{\left(x- c k \right)^2}{2}} $ which results in 
\begin{align*}
N^2\sum_{ k=1... N}  e^{-\frac{\left(x- c k \right)^2}{2}} >f(x) \ge \sum_{ k=1... N}  e^{-\frac{\left(x- c k \right)^2}{2}}
\end{align*}

I was wondering if something more clever can be done?  My ultimate goal is to evaluate or find good bounds on
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) dx
\end{align*}
Thanks a lot for any help.